# Checking for sublist in list

Tags: python, sublist

The Question is: You are to write a function, called `isSublist()`, which takes two arguments (`list, sublist`) and returns `1` if sublist is a sub-list of list, and 0 otherwise.

So i have my code however I get `True` when the sublist is not in list. Any suggestions on fixing this please?

```
 def isSublist(list, sublist):
    for i in range(len(list)-(len(sublist))+1):
        return True
    if sublist==list[i:i+(len(sublist))]:
        return False
```

sample input:

```
list= (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
isSublist(list, [1,2,3])
output:
True
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input and expected output? When you say sublist, do you mean as in `[1,2,3] in [[1,2,3], [5,6,7]]`, or do you mean `[1,2,3] in [1,2,3,4,5,6]`?

Comment: Please define briefly what do you mean by a sublist of a list

Comment: And does order count? Would you like the same output for the two sublists `[1, 2, 3]` and `[2, 3, 1]`?

Comment: by sublist I mean in list [1,2,3,4] is the sublist of [1,2] in list. If so print True, if not False

Comment: What about `sublist = [2, 1]`? And what if `list = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]` and `sublist = [1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: @SteinarLima the sublist cannot be in reverse. the sublist must appear in the list exactly like list

Answer (score 7):

You can break this up by getting all the slices the size of the sublist, and comparing equality:

```
def n_slices(n, list_):
    for i in xrange(len(list_) + 1 - n):
        yield list_[i:i+n]

def isSublist(list_, sub_list):
    for slice_ in n_slices(len(sub_list), list_):
        if slice_ == sub_list:
            return True
    return False
```

To cover the issue of ordering. A list is, by definition, ordered. If we want to ignore ordering, you can do sets:

```
def isSubset(list_, sub_list):
    return set(sub_list) <= set(list_)
```

If we need to cover repeated elements and ignore ordering, you're now in the realm of multisets:

```
def isSubset(list_, sub_list):
    for item in sub_list:
        if sub_list.count(item) > list_.count(item):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Sets have a `<=` operator, no need to use union. `return set(sub_list) <= set(list_)`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def isSublist(originallist,sublist,biglist):
    if not sublist:
        return True
    if not biglist:
        return False
    if sublist[0]==biglist[0]:
        return isSublist(originallist,sublist[1:],biglist[1:]) or isSublist(originallist,sublist,biglist[1:])
    return isSublist(originallist,originallist,biglist[1:])
```

test output:

```
>>> isSublist([1,2,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,3,4])
False
>>> isSublist([1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4])
True
>>>
```

Edited for sublists, not subset. Uglier, but works. Could add a wrapper to avoid confusion of parameters.

```
def sublist(a,b):
    isSublist(a,a,b)
```

Comment: `isSublist([1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4])` returns `True`, incorrectly.

Comment: OP hasn't stated if order is of importance, so you coulnd't possibly be so sure.

Comment: Sublist, not subset. Subset would be a simple `return set(sublist) <= set(list)`

Comment: its a sublist not subset

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that in Python`(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`isn't technically a`list`, it's a`tuple` -- which is essentially a immutable (unchangeable)`list`. Also, you should avoid naming things in your program the same as built-in functions and types, because occasionally you need to reference them and your own definition would hide the ones provided by the system.

One easy way to get around this is to just appending an`_`to the end of the name, as done in the following which tries to turn convert the argument into a`list`if it isn't one initially. It doesn't test the type of the`sublist` argument, but a similar check might be appropriate for it, too.

```
def isSublist(list_, sublist):
    if not isinstance(list_, list):
        list_ = list(list_)
    sublen = len(sublist)
    for i in xrange(len(list_)-sublen+1):
        if list_[i:i+sublen] == sublist:
            return True
    return False

list_ = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
print subfunc(list_, [0,1])  # --> True
print subfunc(list_, [1,2,3])  # --> True
print subfunc(list_, [4,6,7])  # --> False
print subfunc(list_, [4,5])  # --> True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def isSublist(x, y):
  occ = [i for i, a in enumerate(x) if a == y[0]]
  for b in occ:
      if x[b:b+len(y)] == y:
           print 'YES-- SUBLIST at : ', b
           return True
      else:
           pass
      if len(occ)-1 ==  occ.index(b):
           print 'NO SUBLIST'
           return False

list1 = [1,0,1,1,1,0,0]
list2 = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1]

#should return True
isSublist(list1, [1,1,1])

#Should return False
isSublist(list2, [1,1,1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just written a recipe for this (this works for contiguous sublist):

```
def is_sublist(sublist, superlist):  
    ''''' 
    Checks whether 'sublist' is a sublist of 'superlist'. 
    Both arguments must be typed list or tuple. 
    '''  
    if not isinstance(sublist, (list, tuple)) or not isinstance(sublist, (list,tuple)):  
        raise TypeError("Both 'sublist' and 'superlist' must be lists or tuples.")  
    # Return early if candidate sublist is longer than superlist  
    if len(sublist) > len(superlist):  
        return False  
    else:  
        for chunk in (superlist[i:i+len(sublist)] for i in range(0, len(superlist)-len(sublist)+1)):   
            if chunk == sublist:  
                return True  
        return False
```

The idea is to have a shifting window (having the same width as the candidate sublist) scan the superlist and check for equality between the chunk and the sublist at each iteration.

That's a brute force method.

Comment: Sorry, I had not seen the original post date and all the existing answers. I'll leave my answer as its syntax and type checking are a little bit different from the other answers.