# How do I confirm with python that required files are in a particular folder and are accessible or not?

Tags: python-2.7

I have 5 files in a folder App:

```
App|
   |--A.txt
   |--B.txt
   |--C.txt
   |--D.txt
   |--E.txt
   |--Run.py
   |--Other Folders or Files
```

Now I want to know if files (A.txt,B.txtC.txt,C.txt,D.txt,E.txt) is present or not and if its there than I want to call a function Cleaner which will supply names of these files to that function. I have written this code but nothing is happening.The function is not getting called.

```
import glob
import csv
import itertools

files = glob.glob("*.txt")

i = 0

def sublist(a, b):
    seq = iter(b)
    try:
        for x in a:
            while next(seq) != x: pass
        else:
            return True
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    return False

required_files = ['Alternate_ADR6_LFB1.txt', 'Company_Code.txt', 'Left_LIFNR.txt', 'LFA1.txt', 'LFB1.TXT', 'LFBK.TXT']

if sublist(required_files,files):
    for files in required_files:
        try:
            f = open(files , 'r')
            f.close()
        except IOError as e:
            print 'Error opening or accessing files'
    i = 1
else:
    print 'Required files are not in correct folder'

if i == 1:
    for files in required_files:
        Cleansing(files)

def Cleansing(filename):
    with open('filename', 'rb') as f_input:
        ...
        ...
            break

    with open('filename', 'rb') as f_input, open('filename_Cleaned.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
        csv_output.writerow('something')
```

**Upadate**

I think now I am able to call the function and also able to check the valid files but its not that pythonic. And I am not able to open or create a file with the name of the file plus _cleaned :filename_cleaned.csv.

Comment: `'cleansing' != 'Cleansing'`...

Comment: Sorry while writting here I made mistake but why downgrade my question

Comment: Because it's unclear and badly written. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @jonrsharpe already corrected please remove that downgrade or tell me some more mistakes I will happily listen to them :)

Comment: Can you tell me how do I confirm that those are the five files what I need.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have added the logic what I am using can you please help me to complete my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to check if a list of files (`required_files`) are in a folder.
You successfully get the complete list of text files in the folder with `files = glob.glob("*.txt")`

So the first question is: [Checking for sublist in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19990861/checking-for-sublist-in-list)
As the order is not important, we can use sets:

```
if set(required_files) <= set(files):
    # do stuff
else:
    #print warning
```

Next question: How to open the files and create an outputs with names like "filename_Cleaned.csv"

A very important thing you have to understand: `"filename"` is not the same thing as `filename`. The first is a string, it will always be the same thing, it will not be replaced by real filenames. When writing `open('filename', 'rb')` you're trying to open a file called "filename".

`filename` however can be a variable name and take different values.

```
for filename in required_files:
    Cleansing(filename)

def Cleansing(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f_input, open(filename+'_Cleaned.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
        #read stuff in f_input
        #write stuff in f_output
```